# In ASP how do I call a JavaScript function in one .asp file from another .asp file written in VB?

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic, serverside-javascript

I have an .asp file with all of my javascript functions. 
incConnectionCloud.asp

```js
<html>
  <head>
<Script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

CCTokenRefresh = function() {
    Do java stuff...
}
</Script>
```

I have a master asp page, RTNWBrowse.asp, written mostly in VB in which I want to call the javascript function CCTokenRefresh().

```html
If sAPITokenExpDate < Now Then
        Call CCTokenRefresh()
     End If
```

I get the following error when I load the main asp page with the VB code.

Variable is undefined: 'CCTokenRefresh'
/RTNWBrowse.asp, line 119

Comment: To clarify, is the JavaScript function a server-side JScript, or client-side? Calling client-side script from the server-side makes no sense. Remember all the server-side script does is generate text to send to the client.

Comment: Is this classic ASP (Active Server Pages) or ASP.NET?

Comment: @Dai The JScript is Server side.

Comment: @BOGLab This is classic ASP.

Comment: The javascript in your sample is NOT server-side.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn you are correct.  I mistakenly pasted a version of the code that had client-side jscript called by client-side vbscript each in a .ASP page.  Can that work?  Or do they both need to be server-side?

Comment: To call server side javascript in another page you will need to include the page containing the javascript fuction to call in a server side include.

Answer (score 0):

Your JScript file should look like this:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE=JScript RUNAT=SERVER>
/* JScript code here */
</SCRIPT>
```

Then in your VBScript file you can include the JScript file with:

```
<!-- #include file="incConnectionCloud.asp" -->
```

Now you can simply call the JScript functions from VBScript.

Comment: I've tried that.  I will compare my code to yours and try again.  Thanks.